# How to write if statement correctly - Python

Tags: python, syntax, boolean, comparison

When I try to run this code, I get an error message:

```
current_time = 15

if current_time >= 2 and <= 12:
    print('Good morning!')
elif current_time > 12 and < 17:
    print('Good afternoon!')
elif current_time > 17 and < 21:
    print('Good evening!')
else:
    print('Good night!')

Error message:

  File "C:/Users/ungabungachichiunga/PycharmProjects/Practice_2/blablablablasomething.py", line 3
    if current_time > 2 and < 12:
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `2 <= current_time <= 12`. The number isn't implicit in there. `and <` isn't valid syntax.

Comment: Did you mean: `if current_time >= 2 and current_time <= 12:`? As an alternative this is valid: `if 2 < current_time <= 12:`

Answer (score 1):

The `and` keyword separates entire conditions. You are asking, “If the time being greater than 2 is true, and less than 12 is true...” The interpreter doesn’t understand what you expect to be less than twelve. You have to write the variable again:

`if current_time > 2 and current_time < 12:`

Answer (score 0):

When using the connector `and` you'd have to state the whole condition again, something like `if current_time >= 2 and current_time <= 12:`. A simpler (and better) way to do it would be `if 2 <= current_time <= 12` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Pls try this.

```
current_time = 15

if current_time >= 2 and current_time <= 12:
    print('Good morning!')
elif current_time > 12 and current_time < 17:
    print('Good afternoon!')
elif current_time > 17 and current_time < 21:
    print('Good evening!')
else:
    print('Good night!')
```